# How do I redraw my form after clicking on the Maximize button?

Tags: forms, vb6, controls, maximize

In VB6 I created a form with some textboxes, listboxes, and command buttons on it.  I set the X-Y positions of all of these controls using something like

```
control2.Top = form.Height * 0.50   'sets the Y-position
control2.Left = form.Width * 0.35   'sets the X-position

control3.Top = form.Height * 0.50
control3.Left = form.Width * 0.45
```

However, when I click on the Maximize button of my app all of the controls stay in the same place, but shifted a little more towards the upper left corner of the form.  In the meantime, clicking on Maximize also creates a lot of blank space towards the lower right corner of the form.

How do I make it so that clicking on the Maximize button (the one that looks like an empty square in the upper right corner) informs my program that the form.Height and form.Weight has changed and that everything needs to be redrawn?

Or, is there is another way to do this such that we eliminate the shifting of all of my controls towards the upper left corner and eliminate the creation of new, blank space towards the lower right corner?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I realize its not your main question, but you should use form.ScaleHeight and form.ScaleWidth

Comment: Note that this style of resizing is frowned upon. Depending on the contents of the form, normal practice is to keep controls themselves the same size (people buy large monitors to fit more on, not to see bigger buttons) and expand a central control (listview, textbox, etc) to fill the space.

Comment: hi deanna, this is exactly the problem i'm trying to address, different sized monitors. what is the right method to use?

Comment: It depends on the design and the content of the form. If you have resizable content then fine. If the content isn't resizable then the form shouldn't be resizable either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your form has an event called "Resize". That event is triggered every time the form resizes.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    'Insert your code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you check Me.WindowState before doing resize code; particularly if Me.WindowState=vbMinimized (usually you skip the code if it's minimized).